# Trying to get parent id and child id using document.getElementById. Error when trying to select both

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I'm using a switch statement to alter the display of a label based on a dropdown selection.

I have a div with id 'TitleBox' and a nested 'a' with id 'generatePId'. In my switch statement, when I select 'TitleBox' using document.getElementById, it can't find 'generatePId' and I get

```
Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference
```

When I remove the line selecting 'TitleBox' then 'generatePId' is found.

```
<div id="TitleBox" class="CellTitle" style="width:40px"> <a href="javascript:generateP();" title="xxx." id="generatePId" name=
                   "generatePId">Generate</a></div>


function onSelectCombo(){
var txt = var.getSelectedText();
switch(txt) {
    case "A":
document.getElementById('generatePId').style.display='none';
      break;
   case "B":
document.getElementById('generatePId').style.display='none';
      break;
   case "C":
document.getElementById('TitleBox').innerHTML = "Number";
document.getElementById('generatePId').style.display='inline';
break;
   default:
document.getElementById('generatePId').style.display='inline';
   } 
  }
```

Comment: There is a typo in this part `id="generatePId" "`. Note there is an extra quote

Comment: Thanks, typo removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a nested element using a class on the "a", so you find the div first, then the class object. getElementsByClassName returns a list of elements, and as you only have the "a", the index would be 0 :

```
var targetDiv = document.getElementById("TitleBox").getElementsByClassName("classfora")[0];
```

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are overwriting the div with the link. You should create a span inside the TitleBox div and set the innerHtml of the span instead of the div.

Answer (score 0):

When doing

```
document.getElementById('TitleBox').innerHTML = "Number";
```

you are replacing the inner HTML from TitleBox with "Number". However, that inner HTML happens to be your "generatePId" anchor element. A workaround to append the "Number" text could be:

```
document.getElementById('TitleBox').innerHTML += "Number";
```

Comment: Oh of course! Do you know how I would append text to be displayed without overwriting the inner html?

Comment: @user2770632 See my answer

Comment: @user2770632 Just edited with your question on how to append

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('TitleBox').innerHTML = "Number"; //this line
//changes your DOM to <div foo='bar' ...> Number </div>, so
//the below line will never work as you expect. 
//you should do x.innerHTML += "Number"; if it fits your needs
document.getElementById('generatePId').style.display='inline';
```